# Binding source to image in button WP7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, bitmap

I am actually trying to bind the image source to my image in my button, dunno what's wrong but nothing appears...

This is my xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="FakeGridBig" Background="White" Opacity="0.1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="714" Height="269" Margin="3,0,0,0"></Grid>
    <Button  x:Name="Featured_Big" MouseEnter="Featured_Big_MouseEnter_1"
        MouseLeave="Featured_Big_MouseLeave"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FeaturedBig}" 
        Style="{StaticResource BlackOpacityButton}" 
        BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,11,0">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
                <gs:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FeaturedBigImage.InnerCommand1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>      
        <Image x:Name="bigimage" Height="269" Width="714" ></Image>
    </Button>                       
</Grid>
```

And this is the code behind, the uri is actually good ...

```
Uri uri = new Uri(FeaturedSmallImage1.Image1,UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(uri);
View.bigimage.Source = bmp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your probably probably lies with this line...

```
ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FeaturedBig}"
```

Depending on what that template looks like it could override the image you are trying to use.